# Are X-rays diffracted or reflected by crystals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics

In the following figure we can see two X rays are incident on some crystal whose crystal planes are shown with the arrays of atoms. It is clear that these x rays are getting reflected perfectly in accordance with the laws of reflection. Then why do we call the process X ray diffraction?[image]

Comment: [possibly related](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/128247/how-would-an-x-ray-mirror-work)

Comment: Where is the figure you are referring to?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to upload the picture. It is about Bragg's formula.

Comment: Please edit the question so it makes sense. Either upload the picture or remove the reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

Both. It depends on the energy level of the x-ray, the specific crystal nuclear cross section and the angle at which the xray enters the crystal lattice.

Comment: They are reflecting from atoms I can clearly see. Why do we call it diffraction?

Answer (score 0):

The actual phenomenon occurring here is diffraction, but reflection is a nice way to conceptualize and teach it.

Rays of light do partially reflect when they strike atoms, but a majority of rays bend due to the spacing between layers being comparable to wavelength(the condition for diffraction)

Reflection is a very narrow phenomenon, and requires angles to be equal. In this case what occurs is scattering due to diffraction but the intensities corresponding to what would be the emergent angle for reflection are highest.